# MongooseError: parameter to mongoose.connect() is a string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, heroku, heroku-api

I am hitting an issue within an app on Heroku, the kind of which I haven't seen at least for a while.

This app is using NextJS (14.0.1) and Express (^4.18.2).

When using this code, I have a problem:

```
    import mongoose from "mongoose"

    const uri = process.env.MDB_URI_AUDIO!,
                connectMDB = async () => mongoose.connect(uri)

    export default connectMDB
```

This is the error showing up:

```
    MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

And I know that the environment variable `MDB_URI_AUDIO` is correctly set up on the Heroku server.

On the other hand when using code like this, it works fine:

```
    import mongoose from "mongoose"

    const uri = "mongodb+srv://webuser:abcx123def876HGF@myapp.yjsbw.mongodb.net/VOICE",
                connectMDB = async () => mongoose.connect(uri)

    export default connectMDB
```

But of course I do not want to use this last code because it is not a good practice to put directly the credentials in the source code.

Though I have seen on the net that this problem has been faced by other people too; I found no solution for me.

Since I have been using the first kind of code in the past, I presume I must be forgetting some important detail, but I don't know what. Can somebody point out what I am (or could be) missing for this problem to occur.

**.... Further information:**

This is the kind of ouput I get when running the heroku config command.

```
 % heroku config     
=== myapp Config Vars

MDB_URI_AUDIO: mongodb+srv://webuser:abcx123def876HGF@myapp.yjsbw.mongodb.net.mongodb.net/VOICE
 %
```

After trying out a few work arounds I noticed the following.

If I use the second version of the code (the wrong one) before running the command *npm run build*, I avoid problems.

Then I can change the code back to its standard form (first version (i.e. using process.env)) and then run safely:

```
git add . && git commit -m "myapp update" && git push heroku main
```

like I always do. And the app works. I am certainly not doing every thing right here, but this is my current state.

Comment: why is there a !

Comment: The problem is exactly the same without a !. But it is there because it was working like that in the previous code I was using. I presume it was there for what is called an optional parameter. Anyway you're right here it should not be necessary. But it does not explain the issue.

Comment: Are your environment variables stored in `.env.local` ?

Comment: "And I know that the environment variable `MDB_URI_AUDIO` is correctly set up on the heroku server"—the error suggests otherwise. Why are you so sure it's set correctly? Have you printed it out? Do you set this manually? If so, how? Do you expect it to come from somewhere else, like an addon? If so, which one?

Comment: @jQueeny. No (I have sometime used a .env file but never .env.local), here it is stored in the Settings Config Vars on the Heroku server.

Comment: @Chris. The MDB_URI_AUDIO variable is correctly set in the Settings Config Vars on the Heroku server. I am sure, because I can go and check. I have set it manually, using the Heroku web console (i.e. https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my...app/settings).

Comment: @Michel, I suggest you print its value in your code. It doesn't look like it's getting picked up. Is this back-end code, or are you trying to connect directly from some kind of front-end code?

Comment: @Chris. Indeed if I try to print its value in the code, it does not work. As you point out, it is not getting picked up. I just don't understand why. It is back-end code. In fact this is an app that I had left aside for a while and I am getting back to it now, so I may have forgotten some of its details and also I have rebuilt it with the latest versions of nextjs an others.
I get this error that I was mentioning in my original post at the time of running the "npm run build" command.

Comment: @Michel Next has built-in support for autoloading environment variables from `.env.local` and is recommended in their [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables).

Comment: @jQueeny, `.env.local` filters aren't a good fit on Heroku due to its ephemeral filesystem.

Comment: @Michel, can you share a screenshot of the config vars section in your console? Just the key should be fine, we don't need to see the value. And / or, please run [`heroku config`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-config) on the command line to see what config vars you have.

Comment: @Chris Not familiar with Heroku so thanks for explaining.

Comment: @Chris, please take a look at the post, you will see "Further information" that I just added at the end. I has the answer you want.

Comment: Wait, are you building locally and trying to deploy the artifacts? Is your build directory committed?

Comment: @Chris. Well, you see in my post the sequence of commands I perform. This is a sequence I have been using on Heroku projects for a long time with success. If I remember correcly I added the "npm run build" step when I started to make use of React. It is true that my experience with NextJS is still somewhat limited and I may be doing something wrong. Tell me if you see a mistake.

Comment: @Chris. I have reformulated the question after working a bit more on the issue. I hope it is going to be more clear to understand. The new link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77493212/mongooseerror-the-uri-parameter-to-openuri-must-be-a-string