# MongooseError: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, heroku, heroku-api

I have the following situation in a NextJS app on Heroku.

In the root directory there are the app folder and a lib folder. The app folder contains a subfolder (components).
The lib folder contains a file (mongoDB.tsx), which contents is:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const uri = process.env.MDB_URI_AUDIO!,
            connectMDB = async () => mongoose.connect(uri)

export default connectMDB
```

At this point I can run successfully this command:

```
% npm run build
```

From now on I want to add a new route to the app, and this is where troubles are going to show up.

In the app folder  I add a subfolder (Channels_Pool) for the new route.
And Channels_Pool contains a file (page.tsx), which contents is:

```
import ChannelList from '../components/ChannelList'

export default function NxtJSRoute() {

  return (
    <>
    <ChannelList />
    </>
  )
}
```

And this is the contents of ChannelList (inside components):

```
import channelsPool from "@/lib/channels";

export default async function ChannelList() {
  const theResult = await channelsPool() // This leads to an error !!

  return <div>
  {
    <div>Hello-ChannelList</div>
    // More useful code is to come here later, making use of theResult.
  }
  </div>
} /* End of ChannelList */
```

Running now this command:

% npm run build

leads to a failure with this error:

```
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

I have been able to check that this line is causing the problem:

```
const theResult = await channelsPool()
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong and what the solution is ?